# Can not specify the size of mega menu in percentage instead of px values

Tags: dropdown, megamenu

Hi I tried to create a responsive mega menu within in a drop down inside bootstrap 4 nav bar.
But the problem is I can  not specify width of drop down container in percentage. When I specify the width 
in pixels, its work fine, but I want to use percentage values in place of fixed pixel values. 
What is wrong in this code? I checked definition of dropdown-menu inside bootstrap file but there is no specification for the width.

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Simple Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMain"  style="width:400px"> 

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <h6>Head1</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        </ul></div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
         <h6>Head2</h6>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        </ul></div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </li>
```

above code gives the expected result. but when changing style as `style="width:25%;"` it gives a alignment issue. Need help I am new to this.

[image: this is when I am specifying width in percentage]

Comment: No one to help ??? :(

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that the problem occurred because of calling bootstrap class `dropdown` in the first `li`. If I do so the child drop down menu will set its width based only on its above parent. but when I removed that `dropdown` class the width will be related to the whole screen size enabling us to specify the width in percentage.